# Need advice on loading and saving data on tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I want to load data from a table in my DB using PHP.
+ I want to then edit the data and save it back to the table.

I can't seem to find any examples.
The examples load data that is hard coded in the HTML.
I see there is code to add rows and edit - but I see nothing for saving.

I'm hoping someone can help and give me some pointers.

(Apologies in advance if the information is there - I've looked and can't see - it's 2am and I'm not thinking straight!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example for loading data into a Tabulator table via ajax [here](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1#ajax)

As for saving it back that depends entirely on how you handle things server side.

you can use the ***getData*** function on the table to retrieve an array of data from the table

```
var data = table.getData();
```

you would then make an ajax request to pass this data back to the server, it would then be up to you how you go about saving this to the database,there are as many ways to do this as there are backend frameworks so it would depend on what you are already using